# What play are these lines a reference to?

Tags: identification-request, intertextuality, theater, samuel-beckett, harold-pinter

I am [reading](https://www.prospectmagazine.co.uk/lives/sporting-life-cricket-yes-no-wait) about an upcoming play that reimagines a meeting between Samuel Beckett and Harold Pinter on the cricket field. The play has references to their works. For instance, they both wait for a teammate named Doggo who might or might not be real - an obvious reference to Godot. The next line in the article states, "A car approaches. A man gets out, standing in silhouette, stage left. Pinter keeps hold of his bat, concealing it as a weapon. Beckett has slipped away." I am assuming that this is a reference to some Pinter play but am not sure which one. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be a reference to the ending of [*The Dumb Waiter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dumb_Waiter)? In this play, Gus and Ben are hitmen partners; Gus leaves the room before their victim is due to arrive, Ben prepares his weapon for the assassination, and the door opens to reveal Gus.

> BEN: Gus!
>
> *He takes out a comb and combs his hair, adjusts his jacket to diminish the bulge of the revolver. The lavatory flushes off left. BEN goes quickly to the door, left.*
>
> Gus!
>
> *The door right opens sharply, BEN turns, his revolver levelled at the door.*
>
> *GUS stumbles in.*
>
> *He is stripped of his jacket, waistcoat, tie, holster and revolver. He stops, body stooping, his arms at his sides. He raises his head and looks at BEN.*

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Rand al'Thor. This [guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/stage/2022/aug/08/stumped-samuel-beckett-harold-pinter-cricket-drama-shomit-dutta) seems to bear this out too because there is a line in there that specifically talks about "Waiting for Godot" and "The Dumb Waiter". The plot summary for Dumb Waiter didn't mention any car/mystery man which is why I was wondering.